# Actionscript 2 Image slider timing

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have created an image slider in Flash using Actionscript 2. Basically I have five 600 px images stacked beside eachother inside one clip called ContentMC. Currently the slider works fine to scroll between images when the corresponding buttons are pressed, But what I am trying ro figure out is how to have the images scroll on their own every few seconds, without requiring user interaction. I have the following code on an actions layer on the main timeline:

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

btn1.endX = 64;
btn1.onPress = doPress;
btn2.endX = -536;
btn2.onPress = doPress;
btn3.endX = -1136;
btn3.onPress = doPress;
btn4.endX = -1736;
btn4.onPress = doPress;
btn5.endX = -2336;
btn5.onPress = doPress;

function doPress() {
    var twX = new Tween(contentMC, "_x", Strong.easeInOut, contentMC._x, this.endX, 1.5, true);
}
```

I have an instance called contentMC containing all of the images.
I have 5 instances called btn1 through btn5 each containing the button movie clip.

Again, The specific functionality I am looking for help with is having the images slide on their own every few seconds (as well as retaining the ability to slide to a specific image by hitting the corresponding button). I apologize for any ignorance on my part, but I am not too proficient with Actionscript.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my actionscript is a bit rusty but I think you would want to try something like this.

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

// Initialize Pixel Offsets in an array
// This is the equivalent of what you were doing before but more accessible 
// to code. It has to start at 0 though, so btn1.endX is offsetArray[0] and 
// btn2.endX is offsetArray[1] and so on and so on.
var offsetArray = new Array();
offsetArray[0] = 64;
offsetArray[1] = -536;
offsetArray[2] = -1136;
offsetArray[3] = -1736;
offsetArray[4] = -2336;

// Setup button callbacks
btn1.onPress = function() { changeImage(1); }
btn2.onPress = function() { changeImage(2); }
btn3.onPress = function() { changeImage(3); }
btn4.onPress = function() { changeImage(4); }
btn5.onPress = function() { changeImage(5); }

// Array of buttons, used to dynamically set buttons to down state
var btnArray = new Array();
btnArray[0] = btn1;
btnArray[1] = btn2;
btnArray[2] = btn3;
btnArray[3] = btn4;
btnArray[4] = btn5;

// Button one down by default
btnArray[0].gotoAndStop(3);

// Setup the Timer
// Change this value to alter the delay in image changes
secondDelay = 4;
totalDelay = 30;
// Number of images in the slider (Don't change this unless you add more onPress and endX variables above)
totalImages = 5;

// Don't change these
secondCounter = 0;
totalCounter = 0;
var imageCounter = 1;
// Fires the delay function every 1000 milliseconds
var imageTimer = setInterval(delay, 1000);

// General Function for changing an image in the slider
function changeImage(offset) {
    imageCounter = offset;
    clearInterval(imageTimer);

    if (totalCounter < totalDelay) {
        secondCounter=0;
        imageTimer = setInterval(delay, 1000);
        // Make sure we don't try to move to an image that doesn't exist
        if (imageCounter > totalImages) {
             imageCounter = 1;
        }
    }

    var twX = new Tween(contentMC, "_x", Strong.easeInOut, contentMC._x, offsetArray[imageCounter - 1], 1.5, true);

    // Reset buttons
    for (var i=0;i<totalImages;i++) {
        btnArray[i].gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    // Set button to downstate
    btnArray[imageCounter - 1].gotoAndStop(3);
}

// Timer function for dealing with the passing of time
function delay() {
    secondCounter++;
    totalCounter++;

    if (totalCounter > totalDelay) {
        clearInterval(imageTimer);
    }

    // If it is time to do something, we can do it!
    if (secondCounter >= secondDelay) {
        secondCounter = 0;
        imageCounter++;
        // Now call our changeImage function with the correct offset value
        changeImage(imageCounter);
    }
}

// Script for button animations
btn1.onRollOver = function() {
btn1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
btn1.onRollOut = function() {
    if (imageCounter == 1) {
        btn1.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        btn1.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

btn2.onRollOver = function() {
btn2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
btn2.onRollOut = function() {
    if (imageCounter == 2) {
        btn2.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        btn2.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

btn3.onRollOver = function() {
btn3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
btn3.onRollOut = function() {
    if (imageCounter == 3) {
        btn3.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        btn3.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

btn4.onRollOver = function() {
btn4.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
btn4.onRollOut = function() {
    if (imageCounter == 4) {
        btn4.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        btn4.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

btn5.onRollOver = function() {
btn5.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
btn5.onRollOut = function() {
    if (imageCounter == 5) {
        btn5.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        btn5.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

This could definitely be refactored because it was done a bit quickly, but it should get anyone started.

Unfortunately I didn't have flash studio available to test this, but it should be a good start. Fire me a comment if you have any issues or questions.

Comment: Alright this is good, very good. There are just 2 issues:

1. It starts on image 5, then scrolls to image 2, and then goes through the sequence normally. So for some reason instead of beginning with the first image, it begins with the last image, and then skips the first image. This only happens the first time it goes through the sequence, after that it is fine.

2. The buttons to switch images no longer work.

Finally, if I wanted this to stop scrolling on it's own after a said amount of time, how would I do that?

Comment: Coderates corrected this code for me and gave it to me. The code in his response is 100% correct, and functions much better than even what I had asked for. Thank you very much Coderates.